# Routing in node: How can I mange the access to my public folder?

Tags: node.js, routes

I'm sorry if I'm a little confusing in my explanation.

I Get this error on chrome when trying to reach my endpoint movies/add

GET http://localhost:3002/movies/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
add:93 GET http://localhost:3002/movies/images/happy.svg 404 (Not Found)
2add:112 GET http://localhost:3002/movies/js/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I have my files structured in a common way, and I have my routing using different paths, like this:

```
const iFeltRoutes = require('../app/routes/')
const movieRoutes = require('../app/routes/movies/') 
app.use('/movies', movieRoutes)
app.use('/', iFeltRoutes)
```

So when I access / and all the routes in iFeltRoutes, public folder is accessed the right way, but using the movieRoutes, gives me this error.

How can I define the right path to public folder, whatever the route I use?

Comment: solve it but adding a slash, in css, images and main.js calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative path doesn't work very well when serving using express static. It's better to set up `virtual path` for all your static files and then use `absolute path` in your html etc

```
//Say folder structure
app.js
public
|  +-- css
|  |   +-- style.css
|  |   +-- another.css
|  +-- images
|  |   +-- some.jpg
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + "/public"))

// In you html
<link href="/public/css/style.css">
<img src="/public/images/some.jpg"></img>
```